# Eclipse, How to search in the selected text only

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to restrict the search to only the painted block of lines? I tried to search eclipse documentation, but it didn't mention about this funtionality.

Comment: `Ctrl`+`f` -> Scope: Selected lines.

Answer (score 1):

Select a block of text in editor and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> automatically find dialog selects search scope as `selected lines` automatically for you.